# Is it possible to have modelica compiler installed on the arm64 build of scilab for Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate, 20.10, arm64, scilab

I'm using Raspberry Pi 4 with 4 Gb of RAM with Ubuntu MATE 20.10 arm64 installed.

What is interesting the Scilab package for 64-bit ARM does not contain modelica compiler. While 32-bit package has [it in place](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=modelicac&mode=exactfilename&suite=groovy&arch=any).

Is to possible to get the modelica compiler for arm64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. We need to patch the `debian/rules` file in the source tree.

The complete walk-through is below:

1. Enable `deb-src` URLs in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` using text editor or by Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`)
2. Get the source code of Scilab package, patch and build it

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   apt-get source scilab
   cd scilab-6.1.0+dfsg1/
   sed -i "s/--without-modelica/--with-modelica/g" debian/rules

   dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
   ```
3. Install the just compiled packages

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ~/Downloads/scilab*.deb
   ```
4. Open Scilab, go to *? → Scilab Demonstrations*, select *Xcos demos → Modelica demos → RLC circuit* and enjoy the simulation.

---

Note: I have reported [bug 1905039](https://pad.lv/1905039) to inform package maintainers in the Ubuntu.